# Update List items through Linq, Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, list, c#-4.0

My list as below:

```
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 2", Value = "2", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 3", Value = "3", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 4", Value = "4", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 3", Value = "5", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 6", Value = "6", Selected = false });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Item 7", Value = "7", Selected = false });
```

Based on it a listbox is created. 
User can select multiple items (though a listbox) and selected items stored as string (3,7 mean Item 3 and Item 7 selected). How I can update the list (before binding) to set selected true for Value 3 and 7?

```
string selectedItems=3,7
```

[image]

I can do with a for loop and search for item 3 and 7 and update Selected=True

But is there any shortcut or faster way? As I have many instances of such lists in my data entry

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as below:

```
    if (selectedItems != null)
    {
       var Selected= items 
        .Where(x => selectedItems.Split(',').Any(s => x.Text.ToString().Equals(s)))
        .ToList();

        foreach(var item in Selected)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

But hopefully some better is there to avoid loop!
Cheers